# Spring bean prototype lazy initialization with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

### Information part:

Application uses spring **context.xml** for declaring spring beans.
I need inject prototype bean into singleton every time of prototype using (sounds trivial). This part has is clear for me on flow & implementation side.

Example of declaring bean is:

```
<bean id="entryNumberHelper" class="path.toMyBean.EntryNumberHelper"
      lazy-init="true" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg name="orderEntryGroup" value="dynamicValueNewForDifferentPrototypes"/>
    <property name="modelService" ref="modelService"/>
</bean>
```

### Questions:

- How to describe in `xml` creation of parameterized prototype (only singleton where prototype should be injected knows about `orderEntryGroup` parameter)?
- How to inject one in dynamic way?

### P.S. - workaround

I can create one more method that can be used for `prototype` building (creation and tuning) but I dislike redundant code and hoping for elegant solution hidden in spring framework.

Comment: Where would the `dynamicValueNewForDifferentPrototypes` come from?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Stateless singleton knows the values. Values are depending on user session or job information.